# urlrewriter 404 error on iis7 use asp.net and netFramework4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, iis-7, urlrewriter.net

i dont know why i could show it right on visual studio
and i could show it right on iis 7 server 
and most of my page are ok  (like this ://localhost:8080/Im-Younger-Than-You-p22/)
only the type of the page (//localhost:8080/Im-Younger-Than-You-p22/?ProductId=22) will not ok 
and i am wondering why i could run it right on the visual studio try it on IE 
but i could run it well on iis7 server 
is my web.config wrong? 
or what? 
i am running the project from the book (Beginning ASP.NET E-Commerce in C#) 's chapter 12 and paying by paypal 's page is 404 
but i could run it on visual studio 
and i also put it on the internet,http://andrew.somee.com/BalloonShop
i could not put the product into the cart

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    <section name="rewriter" requirePermission="false" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.Configuration.RewriterConfigurationSectionHandler,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" />

    </configSections>

  <rewriter>
    <!-- Rewrite department pages -->
    <rewrite url="^.*-d([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentID=$1" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^.*-d([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentID=$1&amp;Page=$2" processing="stop" />

    <!-- Rewrite category pages -->
    <rewrite url="^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentId=$1&amp;CategoryId=$2" processing="stop" />
    <rewrite url="^.*-d([0-9]+)/.*-c([0-9]+)/page-([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/Catalog.aspx?DepartmentId=$1&amp;CategoryId=$2&amp;Page=$3" processing="stop" />

    <!-- Rewrite product details pages -->
    <rewrite url="^.*-p([0-9]+)/?$" to="~/Product.aspx?ProductId=$1" processing="stop" />
  </rewriter>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PaypalUrl" value="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_cart" />
    <add key="PaypalEmail" value="ghj147852000@gmail.com" />
    <add key="PaypalCurrency" value="USD" />
    <add key="PaypalReturnUrl" value="http://www.example.com" />
    <add key="PaypalCancelUrl" value="http://www.example.com" />
    <add key="MailServer" value="mail server address" />
    <add key="MailUsername" value="mail username " />
    <add key="MailPassword" value="mail password" />
    <add key="MailFrom" value="mail address" />
    <add key="EnableErrorLogEmail" value="false" />
    <add key="ErrorLogEmail" value="ghj147852000@gmail.com" />
    <add key="ProductsPerPage" value="6"/>
    <add key="ProductDescriptionLength" value="70"/>
    <add key="SiteName" value="BalloonShop"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BalloonShopConnection" connectionString="Server=(local)\SqlExpress; Database=BalloonShop; User=balloonshop; Password=ecommerce" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <remove name="LocalSqlServer"/>
    <add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local)\SqlExpress; Database=BalloonShop; User=balloonshop; Password=ecommerce" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

  <location path="AdminDepartments.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="AdminCategories.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="AdminProducts.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="AdminProductDetails.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <location path="AdminProductAttributes.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Administrators" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>

  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-US"/>
        <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
        <compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
        <!--
            The <authentication> iontion enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="BalloonShopLogin" loginUrl="Login.aspx" path="/" protection="All" timeout="60">
      </forms>
    </authentication>


    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->

    <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="~/Oops.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/NotFound.aspx" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Oops.aspx" />
    </customErrors>

    <pages theme="BalloonShopDefault">
            <controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <httpHandlers>
            <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <httpModules>
            <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule,Intelligencia.UrlRewriter" name="UrlRewriter" />
    </httpModules>
    </system.web>
    <system.codedom>
        <compilers>
            <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
            <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
                <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
                <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
            </compiler>
        </compilers>
    </system.codedom>
    <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <modules>
      <add name="UrlRewriter" type="Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule" />
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
            <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>

    </modules>
        <handlers>
            <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
            <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
            <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need install rewrite module on your IIS first.

Please refer to http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module